# neighborhood base topology

Tags: general-topology

Hello how to show the following:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $x \in X$ and $\tau_x$ is the neighborhood filter of $x$.

Then each $U \in \tau_x$ contains a 
$V \in \tau_x$ such that $U \in \tau_y$ for all $y \in V$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $U\in\tau_x$. For any $y\in X$, $U\in\tau_y$ if and only if $y\in U$, so you’re looking for a $V\in\tau_x$ such that $V\subseteq U$ and $y\in U$ for all $y\in V$. There’s a *very* obvious choice for $V$ if you just stop and think about it for a moment. (In fact there’s only one possible choice.)

Comment: @Cameron: It’s a cute problem: I actually chuckled when I realized what was going on.

Comment: It's one of the 4 (IIRC) axioms for a neighbourhood system, when we want to define topologies using those. This shows that the neighbourhood systems in a topological space satisfy the axiom.